# Replace "-" with NULL with Derived Column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, datatypes

I am extracting information from an excel sheet and loading it into a database. Before I load it into the database, I must transform all of the `"-"` in the excel sheet to `NULL` values.

I am currently trying to do this with the derived column transformation in a data flow object. It works if the data type is a Unicode string `[DT_WSTR]`, however it will not work with a double-precision float `[DT_R8]`.

The expression that works for the unicode strings is below.

```
[EquipmentID]  == "-" ? (DT_WSTR,50)NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [EquipmentID]
```

The expression that is not working for the double-precision floats is below.

```
[SideDoorType] == "-" ? (DT_R8)NULL(DT_R8) : [SideDoorType]
```

Comment: I'm confused. A column in a data flow is always going to be the same data type, they can't be mixed. A float won't hold the value `-` because that's not a number (or a NULL)

Comment: Sometimes zeros are formatted as - in Excel. But they are still a 0 under the covers. I would expect SSIS will see the 0 not the - on the numeric column. Can you check this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to cast `NULL()` function `(DT_R8)NULL(DT_R8)` you can use it without casting. Only you will need to cast when working with `DT_STR`. Read more at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/null-ssis-expression
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455146/why-does-this-ssis-conversion-expression-syntax-the-way-it-is

The problem is that you are using a *Case statement* that returns 2 datatypes

```
[SideDoorType] == "-" ? NULL(DT_R8) : [SideDoorType]
```

You are comparing `[SideDoorType]` column to a string value `"-"`,
if it is equal, you are trying to return a double-precision floats `NULL` , else you are returning `[SideDoorType]` column.

you can try using the following expression it might be working

*if `[SideDoorType]` type is `DT_WSTR` or `DT_STR`, you have to cast the column in the false part expression*

```
[SideDoorType] == "-" ? NULL(DT_R8) : (DT_R8)[SideDoorType]
```

*if  `[SideDoorType]` type is `DT_R8`, you have to cast the column in the comparaison expression*

```
 (DT_WSTR,50,1256)[SideDoorType] == "-" ? NULL(DT_R8) : [SideDoorType]
```

And if these two expressions are not working, you have to use a string dataType like the first expression you provided, because it looks like your column contains values that cannot be converted to `DT_R8`, or use a `Script Component` instead of `Derived Column` and write a script to clean your data before casting it to float

Comment: Also, there's no need to cast the result of NULL function to the target data type: `(DT_R8)NULL(DT_R8)` should be replaced with `NULL(DT_R8)`

Comment: @AdánBucio i fix it. Thx